# read the csv file with pandas

Tags: pandas, opencsv

file_contents = file.stream.read().decode("utf-8")

I have just started reading the csv file through postman. I want to get the data and add it to the database. I am getting the output in string format. I want the file uploaded to be as csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the basic template. I don't have much info or input from your side so I can't test it myself. But this is how I did in one of my project. So free to modify the code.

### To download as csv:

```
def get_table_download_link(df):
    """Generates a link allowing the data in a given panda dataframe to be downloaded
    in:  dataframe
    out: href string
    """
    csv = df.to_csv(index=False)
    b64 = base64.b64encode(csv.encode()).decode()  # some strings <-> bytes conversions necessary here
    href = f'<a href="data:file/csv;base64,{b64}">Download csv file</a>'
```

### To upload as CSV:

```
decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')))
```

Comment: hi @Pygirl,i want a code for which to read the data of the csv file which is uploaded a from pc through postman

Comment: When you will upload the content of CSV file will be in string form. You have to decode it.